Do Seeded Orderby Rand Queries Benefit from DB Caching?
I'm aware that various object caching plugins give you the benefit of caching results from frequent database queries. So that repeated queries return a cached result set rather than running the query again.
I've also heard that using Orderby => Rand repeats queries and doesn't allow caching because the results change every time.
Am I correct in assuming that if I use the seed rand(x) Orderby, such as a date as an integer, I can benefit from caching? Has anyone tested this?

In my experience randomness is a lazy escape way from deciding what logic should be applied when having to show some posts. If it really do not matter you might as well display the latest ones.

Ordering refers to a custom post type rather than posts, business listings which should be fairly randomised periodically so that everyone gets a fair share of the "first page"

and how do you know if its "fair share" ;) ? displaying something when there is no traffic is not the same as displaying when its top traffic. Anyway some sort of "sliding window" will make sure everybody gets to be displayed once in a cycle, and probably easier to implement, at least without the need to worry about cache stability and the need to invalidate it

The work around I found for this was to maintain an array of IDs for 'ads' that I would update when a new ad is created or an old one is deleted/unpublished.  The array is loaded as a string of IDs separated by commas, I then convert that into an actual array using JS and then run a randomizer in JS to select one ID, then use AJAX to call all the data for that one.  It's lighting quick.

Looking at the source of class-wp-query.php (ie, the WP_Query code), I find this:
        /*
         * Ensure the ID database query is able to be cached.
         *
         * Random queries are expected to have unpredictable results and
         * cannot be cached. Note the space before `RAND` in the string
         * search, that to ensure against a collision with another
         * function.
         *
         * If `$fields` has been modified by the `posts_fields`,
         * `posts_fields_request`, `post_clauses` or `posts_clauses_request`
         * filters, then caching is disabled to prevent caching collisions.
         */
        $id_query_is_cacheable = ! str_contains( strtoupper( $orderby ), ' RAND(' );

...which suggests that, even with seeded randomness à la RAND(x), the query won't get cached.

guess this is the right answer, but as a note you can always implement your own caching at some higher layer.

True. I assumed OP was asking about WordPress's built-in caching.

my impression as well.
